# CSS/HTML text area in form resize

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea, window-resize

How do I make the text area in the Comment section to be as big as the section not only one row and start from the begging of the section not the middle. 
[Here](http://codepen.io/kiradead/pen/GZYBWy) is the link to the code.

HTML

```
  <body bgcolor="#00BCD4">

  <div>
    <h1>Contact me</h1>

    <form action="MAILTO:me@me.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <label for="name"><font face="Roboto"><font color="red">*</font>Name</font>
            </label>
      <input type="text" name="name" required>
      <br>
      <label for="email"><font face="Roboto"><font color="red">*</font>E-mail</font>
            </label>
      <input type="text" name="mail" required>
      <br>
      <label for="comment"><font face="Roboto"><font color="red">*</font>Comment</font>
            </label>
      <input type="text" name="comment" style="height:220px;">
      <input type="submit" value="Send">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
    <h2>or you can contact me in game @</h2>
    </div>

  </body>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 110%;
}

input[type=reset] {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 110%;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

input[type=reset]:hover {
  background-color: #d32f2f;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

form {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 110%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use textarea in your form

```
<textarea cols="9(as u r desire)" rows="9(as u r desire)" name="comment"></textarea>
```

instead of this :

```
<input type="text" style="height:220px;" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `<textarea></textarea>` rather than an `<input type="text">`.